# How to find packages corresponding to particular library versions

Tags: centos, shared-libraries, yum

I have a server on which I installed CentOS 6.5.

Now I had to install some rpms (IBM's Tivoli Backup Client) but this didn't work,
due to failed dependencies:

```
[root@server1 tivoli-install]# rpm -ihv TIVsm-APIcit.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
  libc.so.6 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libdl.so.2 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libm.so.6 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libnsl.so.1 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libpthread.so.0 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libstdc++.so.5 is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libstdc++.so.5(CXXABI_1.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libstdc++.so.5(GLIBCPP_3.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
  libstdc++.so.5(GLIBCPP_3.2.2) is needed by TIVsm-APIcit-6.4.1-3.x86_64
```

As far as i can tell, i have all the "missing" libraries but in the wrong version.
My shared libraries all have version 2.12:

```
[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libc.so`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  12 Jan  9 13:13 /lib64/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.12.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 253 Nov 21 22:21 /usr/lib64/libc.so

[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libdl.so`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Jan  9 13:13 /lib64/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Jan  9 13:14 /usr/lib64/libdl.so -> ../../lib64/libdl.so.2

[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libm.so`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 12 Jan  9 13:13 /lib64/libm.so.6 -> libm-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jan  9 13:14 /usr/lib64/libm.so -> ../../lib64/libm.so.6

[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libnsl.so`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Jan  9 13:13 /lib64/libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 Jan  9 13:14 /usr/lib64/libnsl.so -> ../../lib64/libnsl.so.1

[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libpthread`
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 145896 Nov 21 22:38 /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     18 Jan  9 13:13 /lib64/libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.12.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    222 Nov 21 22:21 /usr/lib64/libpthread.so
```

The others also are present in the wrong version:

```
[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libstdc++`
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root      19 Jan  9 13:13 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root  989840 Nov 21 19:08 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 2810858 Nov 21 19:08 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.a
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root      37 Jan 14 13:10 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so -> ../../../../lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13

[root@server1 tivoli-install]# ls -l `locate libgcc_s.so`
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 Jan  9 13:12 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 20 Jan 14 12:49 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libgcc_s.so -> /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Can somebody tell me how i can find the packages i need to install to fix the failed dependencies?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When installing the Tivoli Storage Manager backup-archive
client and API on a 64-bit RHEL 6 system, you might run into
errors like the following:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
   libstdc++.so.6 is needed by TIVsm-API...
```

In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, if a package was available for both
the main and the compatibility architectures, both architectures of
the package were installed by default.
In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, only the package for the primary
architecture is installed by default.
To avoid problems during the backup-archive client and API installation
on a 64-bit machine, be sure to install libstdc++ and **compat-libstdc++**
packages for 32-bit as well.

```
root# yum list "compat-libstdc*"
```

Write down the packets listed and install.

```
root# yum install "compat-libstdc++-33.i686" "compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64"
```

Good luck !

Marco Lucena
Recife - Pernambuco - Brazil